# Client is sending SMTP emails but they are not recorded in the "Sent" folder in webclients

Tags: smtp, email-server, imap, smtp-auth

I have been using instantly.ai to send emails. I connected IONOS.ca and JustHost.com mailboxes to instantly and it works fine (warmup, receiving and sending [yes other emails receive the emails sent, and my mailbox inboxes show the warmup emails are coming in]). However, sent emails never show up in the webmail (IONOS.ca & JustHost.com mailboxes) sent folder.

I use SMTP/IMAP settings.

I tried speaking with instantly support, and IONOS.ca support, and JustHost.com support and they said it is the other persons problem... this is frustrating because it seems that nobody knows what is going on.

I do not know what to ask. Now I am at an impasse. I do not know what settings must be changed or edited.

Please help me figure out how to fix this issue myself or what is the correct question to ask support, so that emails sent through the instantly client show up in the sent folders on IONOS and JustHost mailboxes.

If you could tell me what I need to tell support, that would help a lot.

Thank you.

p.s. everything works perfectly well on Google mailboxes and Office365 mailboxes, but not IONOS and JustHost

p.s.s. I spoke with JustHost support and they changed some routing option and mx records and said it would help. It did not.

Comment: just in case it still matters... the answer [was posted very long ago here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970938/postfix-and-save-to-sent-mail-dir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is that the *client* is responsible for writing a message to the sent folder. The SMTP server need not even be the same system as the one holding the users mail, and may have no method of writing the message.

One way of solving this is to BCC yourself on the outgoing messages, and create a rule to write messages from yourself to Sent folder in .procmailrc or similar.

Comment: I am not very good with this terminology, so I need some clarification.

Is the client instantly.ai? And SMTP server would be what, the DNS?
Why would I  BCC rather than CC?
Where would I create this rule, and do you have an example?
Would this method keep the sends and replies in one "thread" that I could forward, and all the messages would be sent (all back and forth made by SMTP & in the webmail mailbox)?
Why does Google and Office365 mailboxes save SMTP email (sent from a 3rd party client) go to the Sent folder while IONOS and JustHost don't?

Comment: The client is instantly.ai yes. The SMTP server is whatever they use to send the outgoing mail.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @vidarlo.

Could you help me formulate a question for instantly.ai support to move things forwards to finding some solution?

Comment: Maybe this is a SSL/TLS setting or does instantly have to change some setting on their end to make it compatable with justhost or IONOS?

Comment: The problem is simply that there is no standardized way to write mail to sent-folders. Google does it automatically if you send through their smtp servers; others do not. Thus you have to work around this by using e.g. bcc. If you do not understand how e-mail works I'd suggest you hire a service that provides what you need - such as google or Mcirosofts offering.